# Automated call with Avaya that plays an Audio File

Tags: avaya

Now we have an Avaya server , Which works like a charm with Avaya softphones , so since softphones are possible,

Is there anyaway to create / develop an Avaya softphone alternative , that can do an automated call to a specific extension provided from DB query , and play a pre generated text-to-speech audio file (*.wav / *.mp3) , and play the file during the call, by some sort of passing it as a parameter.

I can manage to develop the solution with Java or C# if needed , but i cant find the way , or a class reference to do the required purpose. So any guidelines will be great to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using telephony integration.

You can do it in different ways:
- register a DMCC onto the same extension you would like to control and play audio from there
- register DMCC extensions that are conferenced into the call (3 step conf, service observing, single step conference) and play the audio from there
- using IVR channels to do the audio thing and you just conference them in

The keywords you can look up are:
- **AES** - Avaya Enablement Services - for CTI integration
- **DMCC** - Device Media Call Control API
- **TSAPI**/**JTAPI** for call/device control

Of course you need the appropriate licenses and free capacity to use these features.